# How do I check is my app ios has Bluetooth permission in Xamarin.ios?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I need to check if my `Xamarin.Forms` app has **bluetooth permission** and if not I would like to request it. I have been able to implement this as a Dependency service for Android but I do not know how to do it for iOS. I have seen some articles mentioning some differences between how this works on ios 13 vs earlier versions, but they have not been very clear.

I tried checking and testing on an iPhone 6s running ios 12.2 with this code:

```
var manager = new CBCentralManager();
return (CBCentralManager.Authorization) == CBManagerAuthorization.AllowedAlways;
```

but it throws a `MonoTouchException`. How can I check for permissions and also how do I request permissions? and how do I handle the needs for different versions of ios? (As early as ios 11).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apple [introduced bluetooth](https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/handling-ios-13-bluetooth-permissions-26c6a8cbb816) permission from iOS 13.

Hence, you do not required to request or check Bluetooth permission for iOS 12 and below.

To enable Bluetooth, two keys have to be added in the plist file. Privacy — Bluetooth Peripheral Usage Description and Privacy — Bluetooth Always Usage Description. Give the description of why you want to use Bluetooth in your app.

### Xamarin.Forms shared PCL code

#### Dependency service interface

```cs
public interface IPermissionService
{
    bool HasBluetoothPermission();
    void RequestBluetoothPermission(Action bluetoothAction);
}
```

#### UI page for checking status and request Bluetooth permission

```xml
<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="StackQA2XF.BluetoothPermissionPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Spacing="50" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HeightRequest="60" >
                <Button Text="Has Bluetooth Permission" Clicked="HasBluetooth_Clicked" />
                <Label x:Name="LabelHasPermission" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="Micro" Margin="10,0,0,0" TextColor="OrangeRed" Text="No" />
            </StackLayout>
            <Button Text="Request Bluetooth Permission" Clicked="RequestBluetooth_Clicked"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

```cs
public partial class BluetoothPermissionPage : ContentPage
{
    readonly IPermissionService service;

    public BluetoothPermissionPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        service = DependencyService.Get<IPermissionService>();
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        CheckBluetooothPermission();
    }

    void HasBluetooth_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBluetooothPermission();
    }

    private void CheckBluetooothPermission()
    {
        LabelHasPermission.Text = service.HasBluetoothPermission() ? "YES" : "NO";
    }

    void RequestBluetooth_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        service.RequestBluetoothPermission(() =>
        {
            CheckBluetooothPermission();
        });
    }
}
```

### iOS platform side (Native code)

#### Dependency service implementation.

```cs
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(StackQA2XF.iOS.Service.PermissionService))]
namespace StackQA2XF.iOS.Service
{
    public class PermissionService : IPermissionService
    {
        Action? _bluetoothAction = null; //Optional, if you wanted to notify user that you have performed action (allow or deny) on the permission request dialog

        public bool HasBluetoothPermission()
        {
            if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(13, 0))
            {
                return CBCentralManager.Authorization == CBManagerAuthorization.AllowedAlways;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        public void RequestBluetoothPermission(Action bluetoothAction)
        {
            _bluetoothAction = bluetoothAction;
            var myDelegate = new PermissionCBCentralManager(this);
            var centralManger = new CBCentralManager(myDelegate, DispatchQueue.MainQueue, new CBCentralInitOptions() { ShowPowerAlert = false });
        }

        internal void CurrentUpdatedState(CBCentralManager central)
        {
            _bluetoothAction?.Invoke();
        }
    }

    public class PermissionCBCentralManager : CBCentralManagerDelegate
    {
        PermissionService permissionService = null;

        public PermissionCBCentralManager(PermissionService controller)
        {
            permissionService = controller;
        }

        public override void UpdatedState(CBCentralManager central)
        {
            permissionService.CurrentUpdatedState(central);
        }
    }
}
```

#### `Info.plist`

[image]

> For backward support for older iOS versions,
> NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription needs to be defined in info.plist

**Note** : If `CBCentralManager.ShowPowerAlert is true`, it will result in showing a system dialog of ON in the bluetooth setting of the device when the user's bluetooth setting is OFF. ie. `CBCentralManager.ShowPowerAlert is true` will result two dialogs if Bluetooth permission is OFF or your app and Bluetooth feature is OFF in your iPhone.

When `ShowPowerAlert is false`, this system dialog will not show.

Do not use Simulator for checking this implementation.

The permission request dialog will appear in iOS 13 and above.

In iOS, the permission [request dialog will display only once](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41946349/8892050). So, only after the first installation can you see the Bluetooth permission request dialog when you click on "Request Bluetooth Permission". Once you denied and later second time when you click on the button "Request Bluetooth Permission" will not show permission request dialog. Those scenarios you can handle by showing custom dialog with button to navigate to settings of the application.

Please use this test application for your reference [LINK](https://github.com/RenjitGit/StackQA/tree/main/StackQA3XF_Bluetooth)

[image]

Comment: where do you get the class  PermissionProvider? and where do you create the variable _bluetoothAction?

Comment: @Kikanye I have updated my answer. Does this answer solved your issue?

Comment: Will test this in 2 days

Comment: @Kikanye if you know how to use dependency service. Then already written answer should work. I have updated the answer with complete implementation (with dependency service). I have tested this implementation in new sample project and it's working. Let me know if you still having issue. And please provide details of what not working as well.

Comment: Hello, I do know how to use Dependency services, and for my case I do not need to have an Action (_bluetoothAction) to invoke. When I did this, I expected to see a popUP asking the user to turn on Bluetooth, or allow Bluetooth usage by my application. However that does not happen. Essentially nothing happens. No Popup with a question or anything not sure what I might be missing. Have you tested your code on a device? are you sure this works?

Comment: @Kikanye, _bluetoothAction it's just optional. Yes, I have tested. It was working fine. I have updated the answer with github link with test app. Please check and let me know. As I mentioned in answer Bluetooth permission request dialog will show only once. Hence if you wanted to see the permission again. then you need to uninstall application and install it again and check. Hope you are testing with iOS 13 or iOS 14.

Comment: I am testing on iOS 14.2, and I am also using https://github.com/xabre/xamarin-bluetooth-le... full disclosure. My expectation was that I would get the dialog upon creating the **CBCentralManager** object. But nothing happens, any more thoughts/ideas on what I can try? do you want me to share my code for you to test?

Comment: Yes, pls do let me check.

Comment: @Kikanye Then it is working as expected. iOS will show permission request dialog only once. Later it will not show. If you want user to give alert then you can show custom dialog with a button. That button click will navigate user to permission settings of the application. Let me know if you have any question.

Comment: Ah alright, this makes sense now. In that case it is working just fine. Thanks for your help through this.

Comment: I know this is an old one but I would have loved having an async version of RequestBluetoothPermission. I'm sure that there is some code to borrow from the Xamarin.Essensials CoreLocation code...

Comment: @OlivierMATROT You can give a try with TaskCompletionSource to convert async. As you told Xamarin.Essensials would have used TaskCompletionSource only. Usage example https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/task-taskcompletion-source-csharp