# How to pass from my app to allow the camera in settings and when return to app don't log out

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, ios-camera

I'm becoming crazy, I'm about to finish my app but I'm dealing with a very complicated issue, for me. Ok so I'll explain, my app use the camera to read QR codes, then I added the permission to use the camera in the info plist so the user is able to allow or not the camera, if the user press don't allow  I display an alert that told the user that the app needs to use the camera to work properly and then the user doesn't have other option, the user needs to push te button "Aceptar", and that button send to user to the setting to allow the camera, and here comes the problem when I return to the app the app log out and the user has to login  again and once the user do this the camera is working properly, what I want is when I'm in the settings and enable the camera and return to my app the app should stay in the place where the alert was displayed. Hope you can understand me.

Here's my code

This is the alert

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "¡ATENCIÓN!", message: "Esta aplicacion necesita accesar a tu cámara para funcionar correctamente, has click en ACEPTAR para ir a la configuración.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    //alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancelar", style: .default, handler: nil))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "ACEPTAR", style: .cancel, handler: { (alert) -> Void in
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(NSURL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)! as URL)
    }))
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

And this is the function to handle the event to show the alert of keep going if the user allows the permission at the first time, I mean in the alert that is shown when the first launch of the app

```
func authorizationStatus() {

    let authorizationStatus = AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(forMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)

    switch authorizationStatus {
    case .notDetermined:
        AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(forMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo) { granted in
            if granted {
                print("access granted")
            }
            else {
                print("access denied")
                self.alertToEncourageCameraAccessInitially()
            }
        }
    case .authorized:
        print("Access authorized")
    case .denied, .restricted:
        print("restricted")

    }
}
```

Comment: Here's the answer for what you need, I think: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41303746/swift-3-camera-permission-dialog-priming-prime-permissions-in-ios10. If so, should I mark this as a duplicate for future developers with this issue? If not, then I - like others - may be confused on the exact issue you are facing. Could you be a bit more specific? Thanks.

Comment: Let me see if your link help's me if it help's me I'll let you know.. Thanks